# Programmatically generate sql alchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have an input form with 3 input fields. The user can choose to fill between 1 and 3 of the input fields. I am generating a SQL alchemy query based on their input. If the user has not filled out a field, then it should not be part of the criteria for the query.

I suppose I could write code with 7 branches -- with a SQL alchemy query for each possible query (ex. if user has filled out fields 2 and 3 but not 1, then query looks like this...).

But I would think there would be a way to programmatically generate a SQL alchemy statement to avoid this sort of complex branching. Is there such a method?

Answer (score 1):

Just chain the filters on demand and avoid branching completely:

```
q = session.query(Person) # .join(...).filter(...).order_by(...)

# optional filters
if form.filter_name:
    q = q.filter(Person.name == form.filter_name)
if form.filter_minimum_age:
    q = q.filter(Person.minimum_age >= form.minimum_age)
if form.tag_name:
    q = q.join(Tag, Person.tags).filter(Tag.name.like('%' + form.tag_name + '%'))

# iterate over results (only now the DB will be queried)
for person in q.all():
    # do whatever
```

Comment: and that will only execute one query? at the end of the if statements? when is the db actually queried?

Comment: @akh2103 when you access the results e.g. by `res = q.all()`